# Why getting only single response for multiple queued requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nginx, webserver, passenger

I have a Rails App which runs under WebRick.

As I understood now, it runs as single instance, and so can handle only one request (Application method call) at a time. So multiple requests are getting queued, if the App cannot handle each request before the new one arrives (off-topic: ?? or does it the web-server [e.g. webrick, nginx] do??). is it the same with the Phusion Passenger by default (that my app can handle only one request at a time, or is it configurable?)

I have two similar use cases:

#### One where three AJAX requests are sent with the same data (say - same requests)

[image: same_data_ajax]

```
$('#cancel_search').click (e) ->
  console.log("DEBUG: send ajax_cancel_search")
  $.ajax
    type: 'get'
    url: "/app/cancel"
    data: {attempt: 1}
    dataType: "json"
    error: (error) ->
      console.log('DEBUG: ERROR: [app/cancel ' + document.cancel_cnt + '] returned an error!' + JSON.stringify(error)) # not really reliable with document.cancel_cnt, but this case doesn't matter
      # ...
      return
    success: (data) ->
      console.log('DEBUG: OK: [app/cancel ' + data.current_attempt + '] succeeded. Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
      # ...
      return
  return false
```

.

#### And one where three AJAX requests are sent with the different data (say - different requests)

[image: different_data_ajax]

```
$('#cancel_search').click (e) ->
  document.cancel_cnt++ // this variable init to 0 at the beginning
  console.log("DEBUG: send ajax_cancel_search")
  $.ajax
    type: 'get'
    url: "/app/cancel"
    data: {attempt: document.cancel_cnt}
    dataType: "json"
    error: (error) ->
      console.log('DEBUG: ERROR: [app/cancel ' + document.cancel_cnt + '] returned an error!' + JSON.stringify(error)) # not really reliable with document.cancel_cnt, but this case doesn't matter
      # ...
      return
    success: (data) ->
      console.log('DEBUG: OK: [app/cancel ' + data.current_attempt + '] succeeded. Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
      # ...
      return
  return false
```

The corresponding rails `SearchController`'s `cancel` method looks following:

```
  def cancel

    attempt = params[:attempt]
    puts ("INFO: [cancel] attempt #{attempt} requested")
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        puts ("INFO: OK: [cancel] attempt #{attempt} succeeded")
        render :layout => false, :text => JSON.pretty_generate({current_attempt: attempt})
      }
    end

  end
```

## TLDR:

So the question is - is the Rails so `"smart" and "awared"` that it aggregates the same requests and replies on them only once for all (when they got queued) or is it a bug/some problems in my app? If the rails is really `"smart" and "awared"` in this case - how and where can I configure the behaviour?

## Update:

can the `sidekiq` causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're only showing that you're making one request at a time.  If you send 3 requests to Rails is will respond 3 times.  It does not aggregate similar requests in any way.

Comment: I'm showing that I making **three** requests before getting any response from Rails App. By `at a time` I mean `in one step` (request-response)

Comment: I mean that your code is only showing one request.  I'm not sure how you're getting three requests at a time form the code that you've shown.

Comment: The code is just the function `cancel()` which I call **three** times (look on the diagram). In the function I have **one** ajax call. So three times one = three, isn't it? Please look also on the diagrams, they are the main picture of the case, they are showing the behaviour within the case, the code shows the logic behind only `one` call.

Comment: The answer to your question is still the same.  If you send 3 requests you will get 3 responses.

Answer (score 0):

You are making only one AJAX call. Of Course, if you put this call in a loop, it will send three requests and definitely you will get three responses.

Comment: where is `only one AJAX call`? I definitely `depicted` **3** (three) AJAX calls (their name on the diagram are `cancel(data1)`). The code below is only the code for cancel(), but I showed that I click 3 (three) times. What do you mean with a loop? I ask why the behaviour is different with different data. Then if you saying that I do only one AJAX request, why two similar code produce different behaviour (one sends only one AJAX request (even if it does 3 as I see) and another sends 3 requests?)

Comment: I don't know whether it may helpful or not.
See this link
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html